# How to prove that $N$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Suppose $\Omega$ is a finite set with $|\Omega| \geq 5$. Let $G$ act faithfully on $\Omega$ such that $G$ is 4-transitive on $\Omega$. Let $N$ be a normal, nontrivial, nonregular subgroup of $G$. I have three questions:

(Let $\omega \in \Omega$)

a. Show that the point stabilizer $N_{\omega}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{\omega}$.

b. Show that $G_{\omega}$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega - \{ {\omega} \}$.

c. Show that $N$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega$.

I've already done (a.). What I did was to get a $g \in G_{\omega}, n \in N_{\omega}$. Then, since $N$ is normal, $g^{-1}ng \in N$. And since $g$ and $n$ fix $\omega$, $g^{-1}ng \in N_{\omega}$. This means that $g^{-1}N_{\omega}g \subseteq N_{\omega}$. Therefore, $N_{\omega}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{\omega}$.

However, I'm stuck at (b.). How do I show that given any $a, b, c, d \in \Omega - \{ \omega \}$, $a$ distinct from $b$, $c$ distinct from $d$, there is a $g \in G_{\omega}$ such that $(a, b)^g = (a^g, b^g) = (c, d)$? And how would I use this to prove the last statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are given that $G$ is $4$-transitive on $\Omega$, and the triples $(a,b,\omega)$ and $(c,d,\omega)$ each consist of three distinct elements (given, as stated, that $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$).  Therefore, there is an element $g$ in $G$ for which $(a,b,\omega)^{g} = (c,d,\omega)$.  In particular, $\omega^{g} = \omega$, so that $g$ belongs to $G_{\omega}$.

Comment: So from here, we have $G_{\omega}$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega - \{ \omega \}$. 

Also, $N$ is transitive on $\Omega$ since $G$ is primitive and $N$ is nonregular.

$N_{\omega}$ is transitive on $\Omega - \{ \omega \}$ since $G_{\omega}$ is primitive on $\Omega - \{ \omega \}$ and $N_{\omega}$ can't be regular because this contradicts the fact that $N$ is not regular. 

From these two, we can say that $N$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega$. Is my line of reasoning correct?

Comment: The reason $N$ is transitive is due to its being a normal subgroup of $G$. (Likewise for $N_{\omega}$ in $G_{\omega}$.)  Being non-regular just tells you that some point stabiliser is non-trivial.  (Or, that it is not transitive, but you know now that it is.)